# Nuget Update-Package incorrectly updating assembly binding redirects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, json.net, nuget, assembly-binding-redirect

I have an internal NuGet package that contains a single dll, no external NuGet package dependencies, and no web.config transforms.

Yet when i run Update-Package on my projects (class lib and website) for this specific NuGet, it automatically is updating my website web.config assembly binding redirects to **older** versions of System.Web.Mvc and Newtonsoft.Json. The website web.config currently has them bound to the latest version being used.

Using the GUI, utilizing Manage NuGet packages for Solution... I choose to UPDATE this NuGet for applicable projects that have a reference to the old version.  Then choose Update

Here is the output from Package Manager: http://pastebin.com/3ySwTRFR

And my web.config went from:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

To:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The NuGet package I am updating has a dll which references Newtonsoft.Json (but is not explicitly made a NuGet package dependency)

When unknowing developer updates this NuGet package it breaks the runtime looking for old version of MVC or JSON.NET dlls.

In the past I have attempted to use the [-IgnoreDependencies powershell command switch](http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference#Update-Package), but this appears to have no impact on the issue.

Any idea on what could be transforming my web.configs (without an explicit transform) during update-package?

Edit: VS2015 w/ NuGet 3.3.0 seems to be behaving better... during random package update it found an old BAD binding redirect and corrected it! [image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Skip applying binding redirects is an option now in NuGet 3.3.0: [Issue #1147](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1147)

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Use following command in Package Manager Console

> PM> Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect

Refer https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/nov/29/updating-assembly-redirects-with-nuget for detailed explanation.

Comment: excellent! did not know about this CMD  - though my issue was NuGet messing up working redirs in the first place , so just not applying them worked for me.

Comment: When I ran this, NuGet kept on using the older version of a package (`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` in my case). All of my projects reference `5.6.0` but it kept on adding binding-redirects to `5.5.0`. Grrrr.

Answer (score 4):

I have a better solution.  Because I gets absolutely crazy when I have to update over 72 references everytime I update my packages, I've developed a PowerShell script that updates your Web.Config based on the packages in your packages.config and the DLLs you have published in the BIN directory.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $webConfigPath,
    [string] $packagesConfigPath,
    [string] $binPath
)

[bool]$isWindowsFormsAssemblyLoaded = $false
[System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace]$ns1 = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"

function ClearBindings([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $xml) {

    $elements = $xml.Root.Element("runtime").Element($ns1 + "assemblyBinding").Elements()
    $l1 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]"
    $l1.AddRange($elements)

    $l1 | ForEach-Object { $_.Remove() }
}
function GetPackageList([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $xml, [string] $binPath) {

    $elements = $xml.Root.Elements("package")
    $l1 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]"
    $l1.AddRange($elements)

    [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$packageList = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[string]"
    $l1 | ForEach-Object { $packageList.Add("$binPath\" + $_.Attribute("id").Value + ".dll") }
    return $packageList
}
function ExtractPublicKey([System.Reflection.Assembly]$asm) {
    $bytes = $asm.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken()
    return [System.BitConverter]::ToString($bytes).Replace("-", "")
}
function ExtractCulterInfoName($asm) {
    if ($asm.GetName().CultureInfo.TextInfo.CultureName -eq "") {
        return "neutral"
    } else {
        return $asm.GetName().CultureInfo.TextInfo.CultureName
    }
}
function CreateBindingElement([System.IO.FileInfo] $fi) {

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]$asm = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($fi.FullName)
    $publicKey = ExtractPublicKey $asm
    $culterInfo = ExtractCulterInfoName $asm

    $assemblyIdentity = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns1 + "assemblyIdentity")
    $assemblyIdentity.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new("name", $asm.GetName().Name))
    $assemblyIdentity.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new("publicKeyToken", $publicKey))
    $assemblyIdentity.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new("culture", $culterInfo))

    $bindingRedirect = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns1 + "bindingRedirect")
    $bindingRedirect.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new("oldVersion", "0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535"))
    $bindingRedirect.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new("newVersion", $asm.GetName().Version<#$fi.VersionInfo.FileVersion#>))

    return [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns1 + "dependentAssembly", $assemblyIdentity, $bindingRedirect)
}
function UpdateBindings([string] $webConfigPath, [string] $packageConfigPath, [string] $binPath) {

    $webConfig = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($webConfigPath)
    ClearBindings $webConfig

    [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $packageConfig = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($packageConfigPath)
    $packages = GetPackageList $packageConfig $binPath

    [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]$assemblyBinding = $webConfig.Root.Element("runtime").Element($ns1 + "assemblyBinding")

    $packages | ForEach-Object {

        [System.IO.FileInfo]$fi = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($_)
        if ($fi.Exists) {
            $newElement = CreateBindingElement $fi
            $assemblyBinding.Add($newElement)
        }
    }

    $webConfig.Save($webConfigPath)
}
function LoadWindowsFormsAssembly() {
    if (!$isWindowsFormsAssemblyLoaded) {
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
        $isWindowsFormsAssemblyLoaded = $true
    }
}
function PromptForFile ([string]$title, [string]$filter) {

    LoadWindowsFormsAssembly
    [System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog]$dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $dialog.Multiselect = $false
    $dialog.Title = $title
    $dialog.Filter = $filter

    if ($dialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) { return $dialog.FileName }
    else { return $null }
}
function PromptForDirectory ([string]$title) {

    LoadWindowsFormsAssembly
    [System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog]$dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog

    if ($dialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) { return $dialog.SelectedPath }
    else { return $null }
}
function MessageBox([string]$title) {

    LoadWindowsFormsAssembly
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($title)
}

if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($webConfigPath)) {
    $webConfigPath = PromptForFile 'Please select the web.config file' '.NET Configuration File (web.config)|web.config'
    if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($webConfigPath)) {exit}
}

if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($packagesConfigPath)) {
    $packagesConfigPath = PromptForFile 'Please select the packages.config file' 'NuGet Package  File (packages.config)|packages.config'
    if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($packagesConfigPath)) {exit}
}

if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($binPath)) {
    $binPath = PromptForDirectory "Please select your application's BIN directory"
    if ([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($binPath)) {exit}
}


UpdateBindings $webConfigPath $packagesConfigPath $binPath
```

Comment: BTW, the Add-BindingRedicrect package console command does not work.  It only updates 3 out of 72 referenced packages.  The script I provided goes through all of them and act on any pacakges in the "packages.config" unless the DLL exist in the BIN directory.