# Cannot update assembly binding

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

My application was generating this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Tbe project dependency generating the error uses Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2.  I had a look in project app.config and found this entry:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

So I changed it to this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.2.0" newVersion="11.0.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

But I still got same error.  When I look inside `projectname.dll.config` I can still see the original entry referencing `11.0.0.0`.  I tried to completely comment out the binding but still this binding entry is always added when I build the project.  I did a string search in all project files and there is no other reference to `11.0.0.0`.  Why is binding entry still being generated?  Is there a cache somewhere that needs to be cleared?

Comment: Probably Nuget. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358370/nuget-update-package-incorrectly-updating-assembly-binding-redirects)

Comment: When I run `Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect` it changes it back to 11.0.0.0

Comment: Even disabling nuget binding option and deleteing entry still makes the binding appear in build output.  I cannot remove it

Comment: I believe you should not check dll.config file.  you should check the assembly versions in the application.exe.config file as that is the file loaded.  dll.config files are generally ignored (unless you specify to load this file )